# How can I force my keyboard to be up on my program's start in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want the keyboard to go up as the app is starting and starting typing into the text field that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidAppear` method, add the following:

```
txtField1.becomeFirstResponder()
```

For more information about `UIResponder`'s `becomeFirstResponder()`, [check the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder).

Comment: Thank you David, you are amazing!

Comment: Better to do this in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @rmaddy three years later and now you respond?  ;)